# Statistics - Mean value and net revenue

Tags: probability, statistics

[image: Question]

From the following book:Probability and Statistics for Engineering and Science

Comment: Any thoughts how to start?

Comment: I have no idea how to start. I tried to follow (or "I have tried"?) the hint, but I couldn't build the net function and I don't even understand why should I do that. I don't understand the relation between the mean value and the advantage on buying this or that number of magazines.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think!: $\\$

you can find the expectation of demand by the formula $\sum xp(x)$. so the expectation of demand is 3.8 which is more near the 4, so it's better to order 4!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But then, what's the difference between this solution and the hint?